# Is there a way to convert a string to a list

Tags: python, variables

I'm saving my list in a text file converting it to a string.
when I read my list I get a string like this:

```
"['layer1', '1', '10', '10', 'pending', 'Pending', '1', '1', '1', [[1, 10]]]"
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert it back to a list.
if it's impossible, if there is a better way to save it and get it back?

Thanks!

(I'm Working with Python 2.6)

Comment: Don't you want double quotes to start/end this "string"? Otherwise there are a lot of strings .. and not happily so (syntactically speaking :)

Comment: yes it's double quotes you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look at `ast.literal_eval`.  It should do what you want.

```
>>> import ast
>>> sss="['layer1', '1', '10', '10', 'pending', 'Pending', '1', '1', '1', [[1, 10]]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(sss)
['layer1', '1', '10', '10', 'pending', 'Pending', '1', '1', '1', [[1, 10]]]
```

This should be completely safe from malicious code (unlike `eval`), but the object that it is able to read are must be simple objects (strings, ints, floats, None and bools or lists/tuples/dictionaries composed entirely of strings, ints, floats, None and bools).

Of course, if having a human readable datafile isn't necessary, you should take a look at `pickle` or `json` as suggested by the other answers.

**EDIT**

It has come to my attention that `json` is very easy for a human to read (see comments below), so you should probably use that.

Comment: json isn't human readable? Switch the single quotes to double quotes and the OP's string is json already.

Comment: JSON would give you both: A human-readable file *and* a sane serialisation format.  I don't think there is ever a situation where you should use `ast.literal_eval()` for (de)serialisation if you have control over the format.

Comment: @Woobie, I didn't realize that.  I've not used json myself -- I just assumed it was a faster pickle (I'll update)

Comment: @mgilson -- it worked exactly as i want and it's simple! thanks again

Comment: @Ennakard -- Good, I'm glad to hear it worked for you. :).  Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

There are certainly better ways, most prominently the `pickle` module:

```
import cPickle as pickle

# Saving
with open("a.file", "w") as f:
    pickle.dump([1, 2, "Hello!"], f)

# Reading
with open("a.file") as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

Compared to Python's `json` module, `cPickle` is more flexible.  JSON, on the other hand, gives you a human-readable file.  Go for JSON if it is able to serialise your objects, since `cPickle` can't be used on untrusted data.

**Edit**: Removed comments about performance, since the matter is somewhat undecided.  [This mini-benchmark by ms4py](https://gist.github.com/3134391) suggests that `json` is faster at least on some objects.

Comment: According to this post ( http://kovshenin.com/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/ ), `json` is much faster than `pickle`.  I've never done any benchmarks myself though ...

Comment: @mgilson: That benchmark uses the pure-Python implementation of `pickle`, and not `cPickle`, compared to `simplejson`, not the pure-Python `json` bundled with Python.  The results are not surprising in any way.  For `cPython` versus Python's bundled `json`, it's the other way around.

Comment: I would have assumed the benchmark would use `cpickle`.  I guess that's what I get for not reading carefully.  I'm also a little surprised that there isn't a corresponding `cjson`.  Very interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: @mgilson: Of course the speed difference is not due to the formats, but due to the implementation.  And the C implementation will always win here.

Comment: as i'm saving many lists like that in the same file.txt. Would pickle or json be faster saving my lists than the basic open('file',"w"), and whiting line by line? reading time doesnt matter to me.

Comment: @Ennakard: I don't know what "writing them line by line" means – presumably `print >>my_file, my_list`.  This would also involve serialising the data to strings.  I don't know what is faster, but if you are writing big amounts of data, this process will be dominated by disk I/O anyway, and pickle will win due to being a more compact representation.  If in doubt and it really matters, measure yourself.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The performance is not due to the C implementation. `simplejson` with C extension is slower than `json` with plain Python (see [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/3134391), `pickle` included). @mgilson This is probably the reason for missing `cjson`.

Comment: And please note that `pickle` can run arbitrary code, so you are introducing a security hole if you are reading from an untrusted source.

Comment: @ms4py: Thanks.  Now I'm really surprised!  I did a mini-benchmark with more complex objects a while back, and JSON was slower.  (I don't have the code any more.)  Well, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think you missed the point :) `cPickle` is the fastest in the benchmark. I was referring your point "*the speed difference is not due to the formats, but due to the implementation*" which is proven wrong by this benchmark...

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ok, it looks [completely different](https://gist.github.com/3134391) for bigger data... `simplejson` is now the fastest...

Comment: @ms4: But `cPickle` is still the slowest.  And `marshal` will probably blow all of them out of the water.  Interesting finds!  (I still don't think this is a conclusive benchmark, but probably good enough for most purposes.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach with [small data](https://gist.github.com/3134391#file_small_data.py) `cPickle` is the fastest...

Comment: @all If you want a faster language agnostic serialization there is [messagepack](http://msgpack.org/) ([benchmark](https://gist.github.com/3134391#file_messagepack.py)).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: mylist = [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: with open('data', 'w') as fobj:
   ...:     json.dump(mylist, fobj)
   ...:

In [4]: with open('data') as fobj:
   ...:     l = json.load(fobj)
   ...:

In [5]: l
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3]
```